# How to obtain a Level 1 format that is not listed on the summary

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

Is there a way I can use a MS Word format that is Level 1, so I can see it in the Navigation Pane, but it is not listed in the Summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by Summary you mean in the table of contents, the answer is yes.  The trick is to change your TOC field so instead of being based on levels, you instead tell it to look for specific style names instead.

See example of the 2 approaches in screenshot below (the first TOC looks for specific style names so doesn't pick up the paragraph that has Level 1 formatting only but doesn't have Heading 1 style applied).

[image]

Comment: No time to test it now, but it seems you know what you are doing. Thanks.